# How to kill/abandon ALL asp.net sessions on server

Tags: asp.net

If I need all the sessions, of all users on a website to reinitialize themselves, or perhaps all of them to go abandoned so that they will re-init themselves, how to go about this besides restarting the www service?

Many thanks!

Comment: how do you keep the session data? in proc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a sort of a solution to this - rather than restarting the WWW service to achieve the reset of all sesssions result, you can just reycle the application poll from withing IIS Manager. Just faster, and does what i wanted it to do.

Sorry if this sounds trivial to some :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do that using out of the box code.

One way I can think of is storing all Sessions in global context then iterate over this collection: add to the collection in `Session_Start` and remove in `Session_End`.

For example:

```
void Session_Start()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["Sessions"] == null)
        HttpContext.Current.Cache["Sessions"] = new List<HttpSessionState>();
   (HttpContext.Current.Cache["Sessions"] as List<HttpSessionState>).Add(HttpContext.Current.Session);
}

void Session_End()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["Sessions"] != null)
        (HttpContext.Current.Cache["Sessions"] as List<HttpSessionState>).Remove(HttpContext.Current.Session);
}
```

Comment: would there be some kind of a server tool to do this perhaps ? it does not need to be incode..

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.. there's no accessible global storage for the Sessions.

Comment: thanks Shadow, I am trying your idea. Wondering... will there be recycling issues if I hold a reference to the session object? will sessiong get properly GCed ?

Comment: Session is ordinary instance of `HttpSessionState` class - can't see any problems storing the reference to all of them. Assuming `Session_End()` is always called and remove the reference from the collection, you won't have invalid sessions stored there.

Comment: Hey Shadow, your solution will not work because HttpContext is NOT available in session_end : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paraga/archive/2005/12/10/502345.aspx "ASP.NET intrinsic Objects like Request, Response, and Context are not available inside Session_End event."

But I appreciate your time in trying to help me out!!

Comment: I also confirmed that the params "object sender, EventArgs e" also done have any meaningful values, the both appear to have dummy values

Comment: Hmm.. is it available in Session_Start? If so, not all is lost. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4648/discussion-between-greg-bala-and-shadow-wizard)